# How can I read a CSS property value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

```js
function displayWidth(){
  
  document.getElementById("navbar").className = "navbar-after-click";
  alert(document.getElementById("navbar").style.width);
  
  }
```

```css
#navbar {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  }
.navbar{
   width :220px;
}
.navbar-after-click{
    width:60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
      
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayWidth();">show width </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not too familiar with Javascript, that is why I am asking this question. In the above code I tried to alert a CSS property value using Javascript. But it doesn't alert any value as I expected. Is there any wrong with my code? How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use .offsetWidth property : alert(document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth);

Comment: you can use offsetWidth to get the width of your div element

Comment: You can use `getComputedStyle()` as explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956136/can-i-use-javascript-to-check-the-style-properties-on-an-object-which-has-been-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) and various other duplicates. If you use the `.style` object you only get inline styles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @treast,monasha  but 'offsetWidth' is returning a value undefined

Comment: does it work if you set your javascript in a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag and your css in a `<style type="text/css">` tag inside the html header?

Comment: @WhiteMaskers No, you don't.

Comment: @WhiteMaskers Use `getComputedStyle` to get the width of navbar

Comment: @WhiteMaskers just try with your snippet, works fine.

Comment: @WhiteMaskers its working fine for me, I'll post the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this script for you code

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayWidth(){
      var element = document.getElementById('navbar');
       var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
 alert(style.width);  //style. all possible objects list in the end

      }
        </script>
```

**demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #navbar {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  }
.navbar{
   width :220px;
}
.navbar-after-click{
    width:60px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <html>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
      
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayWidth();">show width </button>
  </body>
</html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayWidth(){
  var element = document.getElementById('navbar');
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
 alert(style.width);
  
  }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.** //all possible objects list in below link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: that's great to hear that you achieved your goal, good luck for your remaining project

Comment: can you please tell me about changes need to be done even if we put `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: for this purpose you should add jquery and user .css() function which can get any property of element 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayWidth(){
  alert($(".navbar").css('width')); //for class:.navbar id=#navbar
    }
    </script>

Answer (score 3):

Use `getComputedStyle`

**Plknr Demo:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/BQEdwqeZgZ1Nc02ZeAzQ?p=preview

**Stack Snippet:**

```js
function displayWidth(){
  
  document.getElementById("navbar").className = "navbar-after-click";
  var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
   var navWidth = window.getComputedStyle(nav,null).getPropertyValue("width");
  alert(navWidth);
  
  }
```

```css
#navbar {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  }
.navbar{
   width :220px;
}
.navbar-after-click{
    width:60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
      
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayWidth();">show width </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by jQuery.

```
$("#navbar").css("width")
```

Comment: sorry,i'm not using jquery i need an answer with java script

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
     function displayWidth(){

       var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("navbar"),  null);
       var width= style.getPropertyValue("width");
       console.log(width);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using offsetWidth to get the width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <style>
  #navbar {
   background-color:red;
   height:200px;
  }
  .navbar{
   width :220px;
  }
  .navbar-after-click{
   width:60px;
  }
 </style>
 <body>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">

  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="displayWidth();">show width </button>
 </body>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayWidth(){

   document.getElementById("navbar").className = "navbar-after-click";
   alert(document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth);

  }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: yes, as the class navbar is getting replaced by navbar-after-click when the button is clicked